# Apache Beam: Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'awsCredentialsProvider'

Tags: java, amazon-s3, serialization, deserialization, apache-beam

I am extending `BigQueryTornadoes` example from `https://github.com/apache/beam`.  I am making a change so that it would write to AWS S3 as a sink.  In my first iteration, I was able to make it work with the following code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

        options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials(options.getAwsAccessKey().get(), options.getAwsSecretKey().get())));

        runBigQueryTornadoes(options);
    }
```

For my second iteration, I wanted to work with `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` to support cross-account IAM roles.  I have the following code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

        AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(options.getAwsAccessKey().get(), options.getAwsSecretKey().get()));
        AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder stsBuilder = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider);
        AWSSecurityTokenService sts = stsBuilder.build();

        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(options.getAwsRoleArn().get(), options.getAwsRoleSession().get())
                .withExternalId(options.getAwsExternalId().get())
                .withStsClient(sts)
                .build();
        options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

        runBigQueryTornadoes(options);
    }
```

When I run the code above, I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected IOException (of type java.io.IOException): Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'awsCredentialsProvider' with value 'com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider@4edb24da'
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.fromUnexpectedIOE (JsonMappingException.java:338)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes (ObjectMapper.java:3432)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run (DirectRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run (DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:303)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.cookbook.BigQueryTornadoesS3STS.runBigQueryTornadoes (BigQueryTornadoesS3STS.java:251)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.cookbook.BigQueryTornadoesS3STS.main (BigQueryTornadoesS3STS.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

I ran with the following `mvn` command.

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.cookbook.BigQueryTornadoesS3STS "-Dexec.args=..." -P direct-runner
```

I saw the similar post at [Beam: Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'awsCredentialsProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039951/beam-failed-to-serialize-and-deserialize-property-awscredentialsprovider).  But I am facing the issue without packaging it as a jar.

Answer (score 0):

This post [I am trying to write to S3 using assumeRole via FileIO with ParquetIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439623/i-am-trying-to-write-to-s3-using-assumerole-via-fileio-with-parquetio) helped me to make my code work.  With the code below, I was able to assume the cross-account IAM role and write to the S3 bucket owned by another AWS account.

```
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

        AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(options.getAwsAccessKey().get(), options.getAwsSecretKey().get()));
        AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder stsBuilder = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider);
        AWSSecurityTokenService sts = stsBuilder.build();

        STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider credentials = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(options.getAwsRoleArn().get(), options.getAwsRoleSession().get())
                .withExternalId(options.getAwsExternalId().get())
                .withStsClient(sts)
                .build();

        options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                        credentials.getCredentials()));

        runBigQueryTornadoes(options);
    }
```

Note: The code is based on `BigQueryTornadoes` example from `https://github.com/apache/beam`.